# Metric space with a constraint

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

For $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \ge 2,$ define $$d_{p,q}:= \left( \sum\limits_{i =1}^n |x_i - y_i|^p \right)^q$$ for $p,q \in \mathbb{R}.$ Prove that  $ d_{p,q}  \text{ is a metric on } \mathbb{R}^n \iff 0 < q, \ pq \le 1.$

I am used to proving or disproving a metric space by validating all the four axioms of finiteness, definiteness, symmetry and triangle inequality without any constraints on the metric. I came across this exercise and I thought of sharing it here to generate ideas on how best to tackle it. Clearly, if $0 < q, pq \le 1$ then $d_{p,q}(x,y)$ is a metric space since all the four axioms are easily met. How do we prove the other direction that is if $d_{p,q} (x,y)$ is a metric we show that $0 <q, pq\le q$? We need to fulfill the two directions of the $"\iff"$. Benevolent contributors I rely on you for your support.

Comment: Well, you do so by proving that if any of the conditions is **not** met, then $d(x,y)$ fails to be a metric. Specifically, it fails the triangle inequality (because the other axioms are obviously fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $d_{p,q}$ is a metric. Note that if $q\leq0$ then anything exponentiated to the power of $q$ cannot be $0$ so $d_{p,q}(\vec{x},\vec{x})\neq0$, a contradiction. We immediately conclude that $q>0$ In the same way one can conclude that $p>0$, since otherwise $d_{p,q}$ would not be defined on the pair $(\vec{x},\vec{x})$ of $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now to show that $pq\leq 1$: Take $\vec{x}=(2,\dots,2)$, $\vec{y}=(0,\dots,0)$ and $\vec{z}=(1,\dots,1)$. Then the triangle inequality says that $$d_{p,q}(\vec{x},\vec{y})\leq d_{p,q}(\vec{x},\vec{z})+d_{p,q}(\vec{z},\vec{y})$$
Computing, we have that
$$n^q\cdot 2^{pq}\leq n^q+n^q$$
so
$$2^{pq}\leq 2 $$
and therefore $pq\leq1$.

Comment: I hardly see through the results of your triangle inequality. What I can see is that $d_{p,q}(\vec{x},\vec{y}) = \frac{1}{|2n|^{pq}}, \ d_{p,q}(\vec{x},\vec{z}) = n^{pq} \ \text{ and } d_{p,q}(\vec{z},\vec{y}) = n^{pq} .$ Probably I might have missed something out. It will be clearer if you could simplify  the triangle inequality a lil bit further.

Comment: Just plug in the vectors and compute, the result is the one in my post